# How to delete Vuex store when the user sign out

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vuejs3

I want to get an object from Vuex store and I want to display it. So this is how I am trying to display:

```
<div v-if="authenticated">
                            Hello, {{ getUser.attributes.first_name }}
                        </div>
```

And here is my logic:

```
mounted() {
        if (authHelper.validAuthentication()) {
            this.getUser();
        }
        EventBus.$on(GENERAL_APP_CONSTANTS.Events.CheckAuthentication, () => {
            this.authenticated = authHelper.validAuthentication();
        });
    },
    computed: {
        getUser() {
            return this.$store.state.user;
        }
    },
```

So as it is seen if the authentication is true I want to get the user object from the Vuex store. But I am getting this error: TypeError: this.getUser is not a function

Comment: `getUser` is computed so it is a property, not a function - you must use it like `this.getUser` (without braces - same as in template)

Comment: In your case, I don't think you'll need to call a `computed` property in `mounted()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use methods instead of computed.

```js
methods: {
        getUser() {
            return this.$store.state.user;
        }
    },
```